# jquery selector for radio button group in which the name attributes value has array notation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I want to use jquery selector for radio button group with array notation

I have radio buttons like this

```
<input name="show[]" type="radio" value="1" /> Show<br>
<input name="show[]" type="radio" value="0" /> Hide<br>
```

I want to use jquery selector for the above and tried the following

```
$("input:radio[name=show[]]").click(function(){
    alert(this.value)
})
```

which is not working

I know we can give like show instead of show[] for the name attribute of radio button

yet IE had problems so by giving with array notation worked in all browsers.

Now i want to give like what i had done and is that possible or is it a different syntax to include array notation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between these different ways to escape square brackets inside jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573178/what-is-the-difference-between-these-different-ways-to-escape-square-brackets-in)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets in the selector:

```
$("input:radio[name=show\\[\\]]").click(function(){
    alert(this.value)
})
```

As mentioned By James Allardice, you can also put quotes around the attribute itself to stop the ambiguity:

```
$("input:radio[name='show[]']").click(function(){
    alert(this.value)
})
```

Better yet, use a class.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you can just quote the attribute value part of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `[` and `]` within selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RzeNt/)**

```
$("input:radio[name=show\\[\\]]").click(function(){
    alert(this.value)
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the brackets with `\\`:

```
$('input:radio[name=show\\[\\]]').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.value)
})​;​
```

To increase readability, you can also wrap the name selector in quotes:

```
$('input:radio[name="show[]"]').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.value)
})​;​
```

Comment: How is `on('click',` preferable to `click(`? Can you source?

Comment: Sorry, spaced... I was thinking of `live()`.

Comment: Actually, `on('click',` _does_ have its benefits ;-)

Comment: I tend to prefer it, but... can *you* source the benefits, I'm curious as to what they are :)

Comment: It cannot be confused with `trigger('click')` (what does `click(undefined)` do, trigger or listen?).

Comment: It's more universal - you don't need to worry if every obscure event has its jQuery method (`click` is obvious, `touch` isn't). I'd bet `touch(function(){` doesn't work ;-)

Comment: Good points, now that I think about it the shorthand being less readable between setting up a listener and triggering an event is why I go with `on`/`trigger`

Comment: Also, you unbind `on` with `off` and `live` with `die`, but how do you unbind `click` (neglecting that they are actually aliases)?