# What is the difference between these different ways to escape square brackets inside jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What is the difference** between these different ways to escape square brackets inside jQuery selectors.

Is there a right or wrong way or are these both correct? I have read different answers (including [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466103/jquery-escape-characters-square-brackets)) **but none compare this different ways**.

HTML

```
<div name="name[1]"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('div[name=name[1]]'); //wrong
$('div[name="name[1]"]'); //correct?
$('div[name="name\\[1\\]"]'); //correct?
$('div[name=name\\[1\\]]'); //correct?
```

All those I ask `correct?` work, is that ok way/syntax to use the selector?

**EDIT :**

**I read the duplicate suggested answer before** I posted actually and it **does not explain** the differences or which should be used... I got that now from this answer.

Comment: Yes, and just the first one does not work

Comment: I am not sure if its good practise/correct syntax

Comment: The simplest and most readable one is the best.

Comment: Good point, but then they are ok to use. thanks

Comment: As for the reasons, sizzle follows those rules : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I read that answer before I posted actually and it does not explain the differences or which should be used...

Comment: @dystroy, added your link also. Good reference...

Comment: @Rikard - You are right, answers in that question do not cover all situations. I've added a new one.

Comment: Not a duplicate since the other answer does not cover the differences the OP refers to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the first wrong case: `$('div[name=name[1]]');` which throws a error 
`unrecognized expression: div[name=name[1]]` -  all other are ok to use, because of slightly different reasons.

**Explanation:**

- `$('div[name="name[1]"]')` **is ok** to use because jQuery treats `name[1]` as a string and not a CSS/jQuery selector. So no need to escape it.
- `$('div[name="name\\[1\\]"]')`, **is actually unnecessary escaped, but works**. jQuery reads `name\\[1\\]` as a string, and in javascript the first backslash `\` escape the second which results `\[`, and this is the same as `[`. So this example is the same as the previous with unnecessary backslashes.
- `$('div[name=name\\[1\\]]')` **is ok** and the inner `[]` are escaped as they should so they will not be confused as CSS/jQuery selectors.

**From the jQuery documentation:**

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

---

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BAw5s/1/)**

**Good to read:**

- *MDN - [Escaping characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters)*
- *jQuery - [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)*
- *W3.org* - [Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        var div = document.getElementsByName('name[1]')[0];
        //now use your own way
        $(div).text();
```

Comment: This isn't the same if there is more than one element with this name.

Comment: Why take a question about jQuery selectors and answer it using vanilla js?

Comment: @dystroy , getElementsByName give you array so you can iterate,Here in the code I have taken first element only